# Parse XML using Jquery Ajax

Tags: xml, jquery

Yes I did search a lot but couldnt find answer:

Here is the out from XML please let me know how to parse that in jquery

URL:http://zipcodedistanceapi.redline13.com/rest/T5Xgti2terxU9AmAQs9VPFv5Bi6gDVVw1TNubPYqhvkr5G2V9bRYRm3tEaKh6FO7/radius.xml/19403/5/mile

and XML output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<response>-<zip_codes><zip_code distance="3.805">19428</zip_code><zip_code distance="3.805">19429</zip_code><zip_code distance="3.35">19406</zip_code><zip_code distance="2.953">19488</zip_code><zip_code distance="1.475">19405</zip_code><zip_code distance="2.991">19462</zip_code><zip_code distance="4.745">19407</zip_code><zip_code distance="0.518">19415</zip_code><zip_code distance="0.011">19401</zip_code><zip_code distance="0.011">19403</zip_code><zip_code distance="0.011">19404</zip_code><zip_code distance="2.095">19409</zip_code><zip_code distance="3.958">19422</zip_code><zip_code distance="3.958">19424</zip_code><zip_code distance="4.23">19408</zip_code><zip_code distance="4.249">19437</zip_code><zip_code distance="4.949">19490</zip_code></zip_codes></response>
```

I need to get only zip_code value from above xml response using Jquery so that i can store those values in a variable and then pass it to CAML query.

Update:
This is what I tried to use

```
.ajax({
    url: 'http://zipcodedistanceapi.redline13.com/rest/Ed9qnMHvlOoDz7KEPmXkwpAZj265net2rCsPoakJZInyP7cFtaZ0zAZSD6Y1kr3M/radius.xml/19403/5/mile',
    type: 'GET',
    //contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    dataType:  "jsonp xml",
    //crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
 alert(data);  
        });
    },
error: function (data) {
        $('#latlong').html('failure:<br />' + data.responseText);
}
```

I get undefined in the errorresponseText.

Answer (score -1):

you are parsing XML cross-domain, you can use below code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'http://zipcodedistanceapi.redline13.com/rest/T5Xgti2terxU9AmAQs9VPFv5Bi6gDVVw1TNubPYqhvkr5G2V9bRYRm3tEaKh6FO7/radius.xml/19403/5/mil',
  type: 'GET',
    dataType:  "jsonp xml",
    success: function(data) { alert(data);

    }

});
});</script>
```